# applying formula on pairs of columns and moving on to the next pair when dragging

Tags: excel

[image]

I want to apply the division in pairs. To clarify Column J/ Column I and the result is posted in column R. I want to drag the formula and in the next iteration I want column L/Column K instead of Colum K/ Column J and the result in Column S. Finally i will drag the formula down and the whole work is done. I am not sure how to apply the division in pairs. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. What you want it's not possible dragging. Excel works that way, increasing just once  everytime you drag 1 cell. You'll need to use functions like INDEX to get it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from INDEX and MATCH:

> [INDEX
> function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
>
> [MATCH
> function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

[image]

```
=INDEX($I4:$P4,1,MATCH(R$2,$I$2:$P$2,0)+1)/INDEX($I4:$P4,1,MATCH(R$2,$I$2:$P$2,0))
```

Anyways, looking at your data it looks like you are always dividing by 100 so another option would be:

```
=INDEX($I4:$P4,1,MATCH(R$2,$I$2:$P$2,0)+1)/100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I dont know how to use the index function. I will definitely learn. Just the statement of the fact that i am dividing by 100 has given me an idea to solve it. It is funny how i missed that simple fact. I am going to learn index and match anyways. thanks a lot. Have a great day!